# Break a dataframe into multiple dataframe based on a repititve column values for all columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas. I have a dataframe and would like to split df -

[image]

The output should look like this -

df1 -

[image]

df2 -

[image]

Basically the dataframe must be split where my entire row values are 0. A for loop approach would be appreciated as my dataframe has many rows and many rows with 0 values
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What are the conditions to split the dfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if all values in a row are 0, and use this to construct a custom group for splitting:

```
out = [g for _,g in df.groupby(df.eq(0).all(axis=1).cumsum())]
```

output (list of DataFrames):

```
[   Time  Temperature
 0     0            0
 1     1           15
 2     2           14,
    Time  Temperature
 3     0            0
 4     1           27]
```

intermediates:

```
   Time  Temperature  .eq(0).all(axis=1)  cumsum
0     0            0           True       1
1     1           15          False       1
2     2           14          False       1
3     0            0           True       2
4     1           27          False       2
```

Comment: `out[0]`, `out[1]`...

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to split your original dataframe into your examples for df1, df2, or df3, but that's because with the examples you've given, each of those outputs have at least one row that didn't exist in the original. If you're trying to perform some calculations in addition to the splitting, it's not clear to me.

I'm guessing you're referring to [indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#combining-positional-and-label-based-indexing) (the Pandas documentation lists *a lot* of options). I'll assume you want all the columns and just want to filter out certain rows. Given your original dataframe:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1], 'Temperature':[10, 15, 14, 15, 17, 18]})

   Time  Temperature
0     0           10
1     1           15
2     2           14
3     0           15
4     0           17
5     1           18
```

You could use `iloc()` for index-based slicing:

```py
>>> df.iloc[0:2]

   Time  Temperature
0     0           10
1     1           15
```

You could use `loc()`, which is different from `iloc()` since it allows for label-based slicing:

```py
>>> df.loc[0:2, ['Time', 'Temperature']]

   Time  Temperature
0     0           10
1     1           15
2     2           14
```

If your indexes were string labels, then `loc` works great there as well...here's an example from the Pandas documentation:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
     index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
     columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])

>>> df
            max_speed  shield
cobra               1       2
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8

>>> df.loc[['viper', 'sidewinder']]
            max_speed  shield
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8
```

And you could use boolean indexing. Using a Python comparison operator, you'd get a Pandas series of type boolean. You can pass that into a dataframe with square brackets and it'll only return whatever is `True`:

```py
>>> df['Time'] == 0

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: Time, dtype: bool

>>> df[df['Time'] == 0]

   Time  Temperature
0     0           10
3     0           15
4     0           17
```

Anyways, there's a lot of different options and here were just a few. Definitely check out the documentation and see what would work best for your application.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question right now. . .

Comment: Based on your updated question, you could instead loop through the rows of your dataframe with a combo of `enumerate()` and `iterrows()` and make note of the index where all row values are 0. Then you could use pandas `iloc` to make slices of the dataframe accordingly.